# Firestore Error: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'F'

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

When trying to use firebase admin on a java application, I received this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'F'
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException.networkException(FirestoreException.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:92)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:82)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:561)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:385)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:67)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:73)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:541)
    at firebase.Firebase.initialize(Firebase.java:30)
    at launch.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'F'
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:137)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:90)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'F'
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2839)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2865)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2713)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3292)
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.ValidationException.message(ValidationException.java:91)
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.ValidationException.<init>(ValidationException.java:86)
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.PathTemplate.encodeUrl(PathTemplate.java:1093)
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.PathTemplate.instantiate(PathTemplate.java:775)
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.PathTemplate.instantiate(PathTemplate.java:702)
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.PathTemplate.instantiate(PathTemplate.java:711)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.DatabaseRootName.toString(DatabaseRootName.java:122)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:116)
    ... 10 more
```

For reference, here is the source:

```java
package firebase;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Firebase {
    private static boolean initialized = false;
    static Firestore db;

    static public void initialize() throws IOException {
        if(initialized)
            return;

        FirestoreOptions options = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(System.getenv("firebase").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))))
                .build();

        System.out.println(options.getCredentials());
        System.out.println(System.getenv("firebase"));


        db = options.getService();

        initialized = true;

        return;
    }
}
```

The `System.getenv("firebase")` prints the following:

```
{   "type": "service_account",   "project_id": "<PROJECT_ID>",   "private_key_id": "<PRIVATE_KEY_ID>",   "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- xxxxxx -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",   "client_email": "xxxxxxxxx",   "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",   "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",   "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",   "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",   "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-s16j9%40xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com" }
```

Even with the unobscured version, I could only find the `%` character once: at the end before the `4`.

The `options.getCredentials()` prints what appears to be the correct data, so I think the issue has to do with an error accessing firebase.

I've already tried replacing the firebase key. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Which line of code causes that error?  If there are multiple expressions on that line, which expression specifically causes it?

Comment: I think it's happening on `db = options.getService();` (line 30), as the JSON parsing above that seems to be working.

Comment: It would be a good idea to update your question with your specific debugging details that pinpoint where the problem actually is.

Comment: That error message is thrown by `String.format` if you pass it a string containing `%F`.  Can you write `System.getenv("firebase")` to a log or to `System.out` or something, and confirm that it is as you expect it to be?  (It looks like this contains credentials.  If so, please don't edit your question to include them.)

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: It looks to me like the error you're seeing is a bit of a Red Herring.  Looking at the stack trace you provide, that error seems to arise in trying to form the "message" for another exception, a `ValidationException`.  Maybe the two are related, but maybe not.